# How to manage the mysql connection in correct way without getting a error

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database-connection, mysqldatareader

I am new to the C# and My method showing a error in `try catch`  `connection is already open` code as follow, when I closed it from Class method then Form getting a error `invalid connection`. here if put all code in FORM it is working. but here I get `MysqlDataReader` as a return value. how can I solve this error.

CLASS

```
   //select all categories
    public MySqlDataReader SelectCategory() {

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE online = 1";

            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataReader categories = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return categories;
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }


    }
```

FORM

```
    public void show()
    {
        MySqlDataReader rd = db.SelectCategory();

        try
        {
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(rd.GetString(1));
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You don't close the connection ever, so why do you open it each time? And returning readers is not a good thing. Return data. You never even close the reader either.

Comment: I have no idea about that..

Comment: where you define that variable `connection`?

Comment: I have a Class in there connection defined as a veritable

Comment: `        public DBConnect() {
            Initialize(); ;
        }

        private void Initialize() {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "pos3";
            uid = "root";
            password = "";

            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `using` which cares about disposing variables and closing connections.

CLASS:

```
public List<string> SelectCategory()
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    string Command = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE online = 1";
    using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        mConnection.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Command, mConnection))
        {
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {                        
                    result.Add(reader.GetString(1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

FORM:

```
public void show()
{
    try
    {
        foreach(string item in SelectCategory())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote - to reduce overhead, I would select only the required column in your statement

Comment: I saw it in your answer also... what is that meaning `List<string>`  pls help

Comment: I didnt use `string Command = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE online = 1";
    using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))`  but I close the connection before return .. it is working

Comment: you're welcome, `using` is closing the connection for your. Exceptionhandling inside the `show()` should be enough

Comment: got it... thanx

Answer (score 1):

The `DataReader` is an exceptional case used for retrieving data from the database, which always requires an open connection to get values from the DataReader. In your case you are passing the `MySqlDataReader` to the calling method, So you cannot close the connection from the called method since reader requires the opened connection. so the possibility for you is to Close the connection after closing the `DataReader`.

Another issue you may face is the connection problem(your current issue), From your code it is clear that you have not closed the connection, so when you call the method for first time, everything will be fine. when the second call triggers the connection's current state will be open so it will throws such exception when you tried to reopen the connection.

Don't worry you can use either one of the following to solve the issue(I'm not sure is such suggestions are valid answers for this community or not, forgive me if not)

- **Pass your UI control to the class method and Add items to the list**

In this case the method is defined inside another class so its not possible to use the UI item there, So better option for is to pass the UI element, the ListBox to that method and make it filled using the reader. For that the code will be like this:

```
public MySqlDataReader SelectCategory(ListBox listBox1) 
{

  // fubo's answer here

}
```

- **Generate a method for closing connection after checking the connection state**, and call that method when while completes its iterations.

The calling method will be like the following:

```
   try
    {
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = db.SelectCategory())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        db.CloseConnection(); // will be the method to close the connection
    }
```

- **use DataTable instead for DataReader** : 
  Get data to a **DataTable** and then bind the required list using that DataTable

Comment: @KBK : coool.. always happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

always use finally to close your connection, whatever happen you must close your connection after opening.

```
    public MySqlDataReader SelectCategory() {

            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE online = 1";

                connection.Open();
                MySqlDataReader categories = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                return categories;
            }        
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    connection.Dispose();
                }
            }       

        }
```